# Is there a way to view old ebay purchases?

Tags: ebay

For some reason, I can only view ebay items I've purchased in the last 60 days.

[image]

Is there a way to view older items? I can search my email for the receipts, but that's a bit silly.

Comment: I don't know that you can. Even in the feedback they make the transaction numbers non-clickable after a couple of months. I don't think they allow anyone to get that information.

Comment: @AlEverett - Annoying SOBs.

Comment: I believe they updated this in 2015 or so, I think it's possible to go back 3 years now. See the answer at bottom of this page.

Comment: 3 years is not sufficient, we want them all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to say so, but it is not possible at all. You should save your purchase history from time to time locally in your computer if you wish to see them after a long time.

Comment: I guess you can search for old emails they sent you.

Answer (score 3):

yes you can view older items.

one way is to click on Purchase history and then select the year you would like to see.
[image]

another way is to go into My eBay Summary and select the year you would like to see.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I always keep order / confirmation emails I get from ebay, and for really important ones I also print the listing page into pdf and save it.

Some old listings (past ebay's 90 days) can, however, be retrieved from terapeak.com or listingshistory.com if you don't have them saved.